# How to average millions of rows of NumberLong in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to calculate the average of millions of records with NumberLong type in Mongo.
However aggregate and $avg doesn't work because of the sizes.

Any good approach to solve it?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what happens?  Wrong result, error message, something else?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [MapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/) for this.

Your map function would take each document and emit an object with two fields: one field `value` with the value you want to average and one field `count` with a value of `1`.

Your reduce function would then sum up both the field `count` and the field `value` of all objects passed to it, returning one object representing how many documents were summarized and what their sum is.

Your finalize function would then divide the value by the count of the resulting object and return this number.

[The second MapReduce example in the official documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/map-reduce-examples/) is very close to your use-case, you should be able to use it as a reference. The only difference is that you only want one average value, not separate ones for subsets of your collection, so you would replace `key` with a constant value.